# Use MediaPlayer to load a remote video

Tags: android

I have used the following code to load a video from mjpg-streamer:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("my server url");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This works only if I use opera browser to open the remote url.
Now I want to play the same video on my phone:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://url/?action=stream"), "multipart/x-   mixed-replace;boundary=boundarydonotcross"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

I face the following problems:

```
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.media/com.example.media.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://xxxxxxx.xxx/ typ=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=boundarydonotcross }
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://xxxxxxx.xxx/ typ=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=boundarydonotcross }
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at com.example.media.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-24 10:34:13.750: E/AndroidRuntime(27778):    ... 11 more
```

I have also tried using `MediaPLayer.create(this,myuri)`, But it keeps telling me unable to open file on client side.

Comment: Check this- http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/sample-streaming-video-mediaplayer-or-how-to-stream-video-from-url-in-android. You can download the full source from here

Comment: The video itself is not a whole file. It itself is streaming from the webcam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play your video using VideoView

```
VideoView video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(mediaController);

video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
video.start();
video.requestFocus();
```

Comment: It says - Sorry video cannot be played. `07-24 11:05:22.554: E/MediaPlayer(29459): Error (1,-2147483648)`. Just to clarify:The video itself is not a whole file. It itself is streaming from the webcam

Comment: You are testing it in device or emulator?

Comment: Okay. I threw away the planning of trying to play the live streaming video. instead I recorded the video and put it on my web server and set the above video view. Your answer did help. Thanks!